# How to enable auto-deduction of a template function that uses static method of another class thus eliminating lengthy caller code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates

I have the following code snippet:

```
struct Foo {
  void do_this(int x) {}
};

struct Bar {
  void do_that(int x) {}
};

struct FooBarUtil {
  static int get_this_n_that() { return 0; }
}; 

struct FooBar {
  template<typename FOO_TYPE, typename BAR_TYPE>
  static void foo_bar(FOO_TYPE foo, BAR_TYPE bar) {
    auto x = FooBarUtil::get_this_n_that();

    foo->do_this(x);
    bar->do_that(x);
  }
};

int main() {
  auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
  auto bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();

  FooBar::foo_bar(foo, bar);
}
```

I would like to make `FooBarUtil` a template argument of `FooBar::foo_bar(...)` for ease of making unit tests so I have changed the relevant code to:

```
template<typename FOO_TYPE, typename BAR_TYPE, typename FOO_BAR_UTIL_TYPE>
static void foo_bar(FOO_TYPE foo, BAR_TYPE bar) {
  auto x = FOO_BAR_UTIL_TYPE::get_this_n_that();

  foo->do_this(x);
  bar->do_that(x);
}
```

I then have to update the usage code as well:

```
FooBar::foo_bar<Foo, Bar, FooBarUtil>(foo, bar);
```

In fact, my `foo_bar` would need more number of template arguments thus making the caller code too lengthy (due to naming all template arguments). I would expect something like:

```
FooBar::foo_bar(foo, bar, FooBarUtil);
```

But it definitely doesn't work I know. Are there any ways to workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with having to name `FooBarUtil` at the call site, just make it the *first* template parameter. Optional and deduced template parameters come after the ones you need to specify:

```
template<typename FOO_BAR_UTIL_TYPE, typename FOO_TYPE, typename BAR_TYPE>
static void foo_bar(FOO_TYPE foo, BAR_TYPE bar);
```

Which you call with `FooBar::foo_bar<FooBarUtil>(...)`.